# Replacing integers in a string with corresponding weekdays

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, replace, apache-spark-sql

I want to find a more elegant way to replace integers in a string with Weekdays using pyspark. Maybe using a mapping or something

A string might look like `'0,1,2,3,4,5,6'` and should be converted into `SU, MO, TU, WE, TH, FR, SA`

My current solution is to call seven-times `regexp_replace`:

```
f.regexp_replace(
    f.regexp_replace(
        f.regexp_replace(
            f.regexp_replace(
                f.regexp_replace(
                    f.regexp_replace(f.regexp_replace(f.col("by_day"), "0", "SU"), "1", "MO"),
                    "2",
                    "TU",
                ),
                "3",
                "WE",
            ),
            "4",
            "TH",
        ),
        "5",
        "FR",
    ),
    "6",
    "SA",
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about using `udf` and `num_map` like below:

```
num_map = {'0': 'SU', '1': 'MO', '2': 'TU', '3': 'WE', '4': 'TH', '5': 'FR', '6': 'SA'}

@udf(returnType=StringType())
def string_mapping(ori_date):
    if ori_date is None:
        return ''

    num_list = ori_date.split(',')
    week_name_list = [num_map[num] for num in num_list]
    return ','.join(week_name_list)

data = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('0,1,2,3,4,5,6',),
    ('0,3,6',),
    ('2,5',),
    (None,),
], ['col1'])

data.show(10, False)
# +-------------+
# |col1         |
# +-------------+
# |0,1,2,3,4,5,6|
# |0,3,6        |
# |2,5          |
# |         null|
# +-------------+
data.withColumn('weeks', string_mapping(col('col1'))).show(10)
# +-------------+--------------------+
# |         col1|               weeks|
# +-------------+--------------------+
# |0,1,2,3,4,5,6|SU,MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA|
# |        0,3,6|            SU,WE,SA|
# |          2,5|               TU,FR|
# |         null|                    |
# +-------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Cool Idea! However, it seems that is cannot handle Null entries very well: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: bug fixed already

Comment: You should avoid using python UDFs as they generally degrade performances.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it by using `functools.reduce` to dynamically generate the `regexp_replace` expressions from a mapping dict like this:

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


df = spark.createDataFrame([("0,1,2,3,4,5,6",)], ["by_day"])
mapping = {'0': 'SU', '1': 'MO', '2': 'TU', '3': 'WE', '4': 'TH', '5': 'FR', '6': 'SA'}

df.withColumn(
    "by_day",
    reduce(lambda a, b: F.regexp_replace(a, b[0], b[1]), mapping.items(), F.col("by_day"))
).show()

# +--------------------+
# |              by_day|
# +--------------------+
# |SU,MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA|
# +--------------------+
```

One could also split the string then using `transform` function to replace each value from a map literal expression and finally join the array to get a string column.